# Responsive Images with Psudo Elements - Is this a good idea?

Tags: image, css, responsive-design

There are many techniques that allow for Responsive images, but they all have some drawbacks.

For me, the biggest drawback is that no solution offers control over the positioning of an image.

For example, a desktop layout might make use of a two column grid, with the image in the left column and the text in the right. On mobile, this would look better as a single column with the image occurring below the text. 
While existing responsive image techniques  allow you to shrink down the image for mobile, none of them offer a method for making the layout positioning change without having to resort to complex positioning and float techniques.

With Psuedo elements, this positioning is relatively easy. For the mobile style sheet, you could use `::after` to place the image under the text. The Desktop style sheet could use `::before` to place the image above the text.

There are other benefits to this method:

1. The browser only loads images for the relevant device (so the
   mobile device wont load the desktop image)
2. If you use your image
   as a background for the psudeo container, you can use properties
   such as `background-size: cover;` which allows for a (admittedly
   restricted) degree of art direction over the image.

I can think of some drawbacks:

1) The image can't be described to screen readers. However, a lot of images on websites are 'atmospheric-images'. For example, a contact page has an image of a phone to create the 'atmosphere' of contacting someone. Describing such images to a screen reader arguably adds more clutter to the browsing experience.

2) This method muddies the boundaries between content and presentation. However, then again, if most images are 'atmospheric' including them in a style sheet this way is no different from using, for example, a textured background.

3) The images wont work on IE6/IE7

4) A lot of sites would have to use inline styles to display the image. However, this would be just replacing the job of an image element (`<img>`), so it doesn't seem to problematic.

In short, this method offers plenty of advantages, with no real disadvantages. 
I've noticed that no websites seem to advocate this method, so I was wondering if there are any major drawbacks I am missing.

Comment: Read this: [little link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), `"avoid asking subjective questions"`.

Comment: The technical term for "atmospheric-images" is decorative images. Opposed to images that bring/convey information (and will have a no-empty `alt` attribute). As your question is likely to be closed, I won't answer but still, a comment: say you've an img and text in a paragpaph. Put your text in a `span`, display it as inline or block and your HTML image will easily be on the same line or not. For a CSS image, play with paddings and margins (left or top) to keep room for this image.

Comment: I know my question is a bit long. However, I personally didn't think it was subjective, as I am just asking if using Pseudo elements for responsive images is an accepted good practice (as no websites seem to advocate it). It's a bit like how using tables for layout is considered accepted bad practice. Although I can see how my question could be considered subjective, so I will bare that in mind when asking future questions.

Comment: Certainly harmful to screen reader users as the [CSS generated content is not reliably available to them](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201205/css_generated_content_and_screen_readers/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this site](http://csswizardry.com/2011/07/responsive-images-right-now/) that offers a solution for responsive images right now and should offer positioning.

Comment: Thanks! Although that solution creates bandwidth issues, it avoids the problems for screen readers.

Comment: if you think my question was useful, please give it a positive vote.

Comment: @big_smile you can also take a look at my other answer below, that one is probably better in terms of avoiding bandwidth issues.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) requires only 1 image to be loaded but the image should be the highest quality.

If you go down about 2/3 of the page to the section titled "Flexible Images" you'll find a code block that will make your images dynamically resize which is better than loading different images and css-hacking the page.

Check out the article, this is the code they use for images:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

and this is the code they use for videos:

```
.video embed, .video object, .video iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I recommend you visit [the website](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) because it explains why these specific rules are necessary and may give you other good information.